# how to use json-sql with postgresql?

Tags: json, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to use json-sql npm module with postgres.
But I was not able to even do select.

I think, the problem is that query from json-sql contains $p1 instead $1.
What I need to tune to be able to get postgres-like query from json-sql?

I tried to use { dialect : 'postgresql' } configuration option but still I have a problem.

As a result of code below:

```
let userCompSql = jsonSql.build({
    type: 'select',
    fields: ['id'],
    table: 'user_computers',
    condition: {
        'os_name' : params.osName,
        'os_minor' : params.osVersionMinor
   }})
```

I get a string userCompSql: *"select "id" from "user_computers" where "os_name" = $p1 and "os_minor" = 0;"*
But I would like to have $1 instead of $p1 for my postgresql DB.

Answer (score 2):

That was so easy. Just configure { namedValues: false }...